# Take Snapshot after componentDidMount resolve a promise

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, mobx, mobx-react

- A `componentDidMount` call a store that call the api
- api is a module with export `fetchVersionsRequest` function
- `fetchVersionsRequest` call the api endpoint using Promise
- `all` is updated by store after the promise resolved
- Mobx, via `@observer` will call component render again because `all` was updated

> Please, check the comments

### **Home component**

```
@inject('versionStore') @observer
export default class extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetch } = this.props.versionStore;
    fetch(); // Will call api.fetchVersionsRequest
  }

  render() {
    // all is an array updated after call api.fetchVersionsRequest resolved
    const { all } = this.props.versionStore; 
    // ...
    return {all.map(it => <p>{it.name}</p>)}
  }
}
```

How can I test if component is rendering right?
I want to use Snapshot feature, give a list returned by api, the component should be mach the snapshot

**My test Home component**

```
it('renders versions', function() {
  const versions = [
    { id: 1, name: 'version1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'version2' },
  ];

  api.fetchVersionsRequest = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve(versions);
  });

  const wrapper = shallow(<Home {...this.minProps} />);
  expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot(); // PROBLEM Snapshot does not contain any p element
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using jest.fn to mock the data from API. You can test your component by setting the props directly using **wrapper.setProps**:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Home {...this.minProps} />);
wrapper.setProps({
  versionStore: {
    all: versions
  }
});
expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to show you how to work with promises in jest. You have to return the promise from your test to let jest know that it have to wait for it.

```
it('renders versions', function() {
  const versions = [
    { id: 1, name: 'version1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'version2' },
  ];
  const p = Promise.resolve(versions);
  api.fetchVersionsRequest = jest.fn(() => {
    return p
  });

  const wrapper = shallow(<Home {...this.minProps} />);
  return p.then(()=>{
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot(); 
  })

}
```

or

```
it('renders versions', async function() {
  const versions = [
    { id: 1, name: 'version1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'version2' },
  ];
  const p = Promise.resolve(versions);
  api.fetchVersionsRequest = jest.fn(() => {
    return p
  });

  const wrapper = shallow(<Home {...this.minProps} />);
  a
  expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot(); 

}
```

It is explained [here](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html#content) in the docs